# Like video with access token on YouTube using YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: android, youtube-api, accountmanager, google-api-console, youtube-data-api

I want to like video of YouTube.
I have acquired **AUTH_TOKEN** using `AccountManager`

using the following

```
am.getAuthToken(mAccount, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>()
    {
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future)
    {
        try
        {
            if(future != null && future.getResult() != null)
            {                           if(future.getResult().containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN))
                {                   
                AUTH_TOKEN = future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                          }
            }
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException e)
        {               }
        catch(AuthenticatorException e)
        {               }
        catch(IOException e)
        {               }
        catch(Exception e)
        {               }
        }
        }, null);
```

Now i want to like(Rate) the video
[developers.google.com- Videos: rate](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) explains how to rate a video
but i am unaware that how can i use my CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI, CLIENT_SECRET generated from Google APIs Console.

I generated this uri

```
String uri ="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id="+ TEST_VIDEO_ID + "&rating=like&mine=true&access_token="+AUTH_TOKEN + "&key=" + DEVELOPER_KEY;
```

Is this uri wrong how can i use `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?` with Google API console's Constants

I am using this **uri** string using the following method which is not responding right result as specified on developer.google.com
I was using this method to get the response(like list of video, playlist etc) from youtube but i think this will not work or working in this case

Please help!!!!

```
private JSONObject getResponse(String apiUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(apiUrl);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            String jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            JSONObject mJson = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            return mJson;
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {}
        catch(Exception e)
        {}

        return null;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did You find any solution for rating a Youtube Video using V3

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [Google API Java client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) and [YouTube Service](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3).

[Examples here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java) and [Android sample project](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android).

If not you can generate sample requests from [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.rate).

Answer (score 0):

In your request, set the access_token as authorization header.