# Like a youtube Video from android app

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am using `YouTube` API inside my android app. On a button click,I want to like(thumbs up ) a particular video that is playing. Any guide or reference will be needfull.

Comment: have you checked YouTubeApi samples..??

Comment: Yup, didnt find any there

Comment: Refer this link it may give some idea

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856551/like-video-with-access-token-on-youtube-using-youtube-data-api-v3

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the following youtube api:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=YOUR_VIDEO_ID&rating=like&key=YOUR_API_KEY

More about this you can find here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate