# Youtube migrated it API v2 into v3- example iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I have a playlist from youtube .

I was using this form :

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLqDQIb5EqNmJEzzDF3L3Sxize_ailX-Lp`

but i know that Youtube migrated it API v2 into v3. How can i get the playlist ? I read documentation , but i didn't understand. Could someone to give a concretely example,please ?

Comment: Googling `youtube api get playlist` gets me results like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804904/retrieve-all-videos-from-youtube-playlist-using-youtube-v3-api, are they not helpful? Can you clarify why?

Answer (score 0):

you can user this `API` to get youtube `PlayList`. try this `API` :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&q=SEARCH VIDEO NAME &type=playlist&key=YOUTUBE KEY &pageToken=%@
```