# UITableView: scroll to load more Youtube items

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, youtube-api

I'm fetching videos from Youtube channel, I'm able to display 10 videos when APP is starting.

I would like to use the following trick (using pagetoken ; [Retrieve all videos from youtube playlist using youtube v3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804904/retrieve-all-videos-from-youtube-playlist-using-youtube-v3-api/18806043#18806043)) to display more videos.

The idea is to scroll down to fetch the next videos, by using willDisplayCell method.

**ViewController**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.model.delegate = self
    model.getFeedVideo()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if !loadingData && indexPath.row == 10 - 1 {
        model.getFeedVideo()
        print("loading more ...")
    }
}
```

1. How to use pageToken from ViewController whereas I get the token
   from VideoModel class?
2. How to automatically increment the "10" for
   indexPath attribute? Is it possible to get the current number of displayed
   cell?

**VideoModel**:

```
protocol VideoModelDelegate {
    func dataReady()
}

class VideoModel: NSObject {

func getFeedVideo() {

    var nextToken:String
    nextToken = "XXXXXX"

    // Fetch the videos dynamically via the Youtube Data API
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", parameters: ["part":"snippet", "playlistId":PLAYLIST_ID, "key":API_KEY, "maxResults":10, "pageToken":nextToken], encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

        if let JSON = response.result.value {

            nextToken = JSON["nextPageToken"] as! String
            print(nextToken)

            var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()

            for video in JSON["items"] as! NSArray {
                // Creating video object...
                // Removed to make it clearer
            }

            self.videoArray = arrayOfVideos

            if self.delegate != nil {
                self.delegate?.dataReady()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

3. Do I need to add a return value or should I create another method to get the pageToken? Please, suggest.

Comment: Have a created a different source code file for `Video Model`?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a general idea on how to accomplish it.

**First:** Check if user has scrolled to the last element with `if !loadingData && indexPath.row == self.videos.count - 1`

**Second(edit):**

```
//VideoModel.swift

if self.delegate != nil {
//Pass fetched videos and token to the delegate method.
    self.delegate?.dataReady(self.videoArray, nextToken)
}
```

Now, few changes in delegate method:

```
//ViewController.swift

func dataReady(Array->Videos,String->Token) {
   //Define a variable globally and assign received token for later use
   tokenGlobal = Token

  //add received array of videos to the current array of videos

    [self.videos addObjectsFromArray:Videos];

  //Here are two options to populate new videos,

    //First, Reload whole table view, not a recommended approach, since it will take much more time to load

    self.tableView.reloadData()

   //Second, add cells to the existing tableView, instead of loading whole table it will added new cells according to the newly added videos into the array.
}
```

Now when user reaches the end of tableView, pass the token we have saved in global variable like this:

```
if !loadingData && indexPath.row == self.videos - 1 {
    model.getFeedVideo(tokenGlobal)
    print("loading more ...")
}
```

Now, use this `tokenGlobal` to fetch more videos using 'getFeedVideo' Method.

Look for SO to find out how to add new cells to table view. But for testing you can proceed with `reloadData`.

**P.S**: I don't know the Swift syntax. :)

Comment: 1/ videoArray isn't available from ViewController. I'll try to deal with model.videoArray or something else :)

2/ The token provided by Youtube is related to pagination (each page contains 10 videos, in my example). The problem is: I cannot pass the token directly to the getFeedVideo method because I collect the token inside it... What do you think about returning this token? It doesn't look elegant :P

Comment: Okay..you mean to say that Alamofire is returning nextToken within the success block?

Comment: Yes (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#response), Youtube API return me next / prev token. As I do the request through Alamofire, yes, it returns me the token with other datas (videos list).