# Retrieve videos from youtube playlist

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I am fetching all the videos from the youtube playlist. I am following the procedure given in this answer
[Retrieve all videos from youtube playlist using youtube v3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804904/retrieve-all-videos-from-youtube-playlist-using-youtube-v3-api)

I am able to fetched 50 videos of the playlist and to get the remaning result I am passing the url like that

```
@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?pageToken=%@ &part=snippet&playlistId=PL_aEw_4hMkBfAWoYqB6I0G1Oe0qtqcqwF&key={MY_API_KEY}",[jsonDict valueForKey:@"nextPageToken"]];
```

But I am getting url nil and doesn't getting any result. 
How can I fetch other videos from youtube playlist??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing right just replace this url with this

```
@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&pageToken=%@&playlistId=PL_aEw_4hMkBfAWoYqB6I0G1Oe0qtqcqwF&key={your_api_key}",[jsonDict valueForKey:@"nextPageToken"]
```