# Make GET call to REST service with parameters in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I am trying to make a GET call to the YouTube Web API but I cannot figure out how to pass parameters using the http.get function. I have used fiddler and made sure the request is being made. I am currently getting a 400 error saying that I am missing a the parameter "Part". How can I modify my code to include the required parameters in my request?

```
private _url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/';
private _key = '';

getPlaylistVideos(playlistId, pageToken){

    var url = this._url + "playlistItems";
    var options =  { part: 'snippet', maxResults: 50, playlistId: playlistId, key: this._key, pageToken: pageToken }

    return this.http.get(url, options);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the search params in to your request. I think this will work for you:

```
getPlaylistVideos(playlistId, pageToken) {
    let url = `${this._url}playlistItems`,
        options =  { part: 'snippet', maxResults: 50, playlistId: playlistId, key: this._key, pageToken: pageToken }, 
        params = URLSearchParams();

    for (let key in options) params.set(key, options[key);

    return this.http.get(url, {search: options});
}
```

You create the URLSearchParams using the set method you can find the full documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the already asked & solved question regarding AngularJS & YouTube V3 API. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982941/get-all-youtube-videos-in-a-playlist-using-angular-js) thanks to [@Sandeep Sukhija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873976/sandeep-sukhija).

Anyhow, about the missing parameter `part`, add it to the request ex: `part: 'snippet'`

Example code :

```
function getPlaylistVideos(playlistId, pageToken) {
    // pass the page token as a parameter to the API
    $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems', { part: 'snippet', maxResults: 50, playlistId: playlistId, key: key, pageToken: pageToken })
}
```

> How to use the part parameter
>
> The part parameter is a required parameter for any API request that
>   retrieves or returns a resource. The parameter identifies one or more
>   top-level (non-nested) resource properties that should be included in
>   an API response. For example, a video resource has the following
>   parts:
>
> snippet contentDetails fileDetails player processingDetails
>   recordingDetails statistics status suggestions topicDetails

Comment: It should be a comment.

Comment: No, it's an answer to his question about the missing `part`. Little bit too much information also to post as a comment.

Comment: Now it's an answer, when I comment it was just the link. No problem :)

Comment: This won't work in Angular 2 with Typescript will it? I know that this answer will work for Angular 1