# How Can I Get my playlist videos from Youtube with angular 2

Tags: angular, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm new with angular2,I need to get my playlist videos from Youtube with angular 2 and Youtube API, but I don't know the best form to begin this task, anyone can help me?

Comment: You should checkout [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).   [The official docs](https://angular.io) are also a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below helps me with this task

[enter link description here](https://github.com/programadriano/angular2-youtubeplaylist)

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this related thread: [Get all YouTube Videos in a Playlist using Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982941/get-all-youtube-videos-in-a-playlist-using-angular-js). From the documentation, use the [`nextPageToken`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#pageToken) attribute from the api response.Call the API one or more times to retrieve all items in the list. As long as the API response returns a nextPageToken, there are still more items to retrieve.

> In your controller, define a local variable `nextPageToken` to retrieve the next page and call the `getPlaylistVideos` with the `nextPageToken` attribute recursively until all the results are retrieved.

Be also noted that the function `getPlaylistVideos` doesn't return anything, it updates the `$scope.playlistVideos` variable with the fetched playlist items. Also the function `getPlaylistVideos` uses the scope variable `nextPageToken` to fetch next page.

Hope this helps!