# How to get comments from YouTube API v3

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

```
var commentThreadsRequest = youTubeService.CommentThreads.List("replies,snippet");
commentThreadsRequest.VideoId = "bla-bla"; // here real id
commentThreadsRequest.MaxResults = 100; // 1 - 100;
var response = commentThreadsRequest.Execute();
```

In this way i get 100 comments.
How get all comments?

It is possible to specify the resultsPerPage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100 is the maxResults when you use [Comments.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list). Now if your youtube comments exceeds 100 for example, you're going to need the "nextPageToken" to access the next 100 results and so on. As long as there's more results to be retrieved, there will always be a nextPageToken.

There's a [video tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETcAYAqDBHc) that can demo some of that for you. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173428/how-to-change-page-results-with-youtube-data-api-v3) may also provide additonal insight.

Answer (score -1):

YouTube API only allows 0-100 results from a video.

See [reference guide.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list)