# Can't list youtube videos from playlist

Tags: python, youtube

I'm trying to get and store the videos from a youtube playlist into an list in python. I followed the instructions in the docs https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list but it cant seem to retrieve the video ID.

```
def list_playlist_localizations(youtube, playlist_id):
  results = youtube.playlists().list(
    part='snippet, contentDetails', id=playlist_id, maxResults=5
  ).execute()
  #print results
  for playlist_item in results['items']:
      title = playlist_item['snippet']['title']
      video_id = playlist_item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']
      print video_id
```

EDIT:

```
from hyper import HTTPConnection
import random
import requests

playlist_id = "PLx0sYbCqOb8TBPRdmBHs5Iftvv9TPboYG"
links = []
token = '' # to get ID to next page  CDIQAA

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173428/how-to-change-page-results-with-youtube-data-api-v3 - reference 

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=' + playlist_id + '&key={MY_KEY}')
data = r.json()

while 'nextPageToken' in data and len(data) < 200:
    token = data['nextPageToken']

    r = s.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?pageToken=' 
        + token + 
        '&part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=' 
        + playlist_id + 
        '&key=AIzaSyAglPb2-eVaoy1muXclkUrfPFtdYEaUcCw')
    data = r.json()
    for items in data['items']:
        links.append('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + items['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])

r = s.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=' + playlist_id + '&key={MY_KEY}')
data = r.json()

# Add the remaining links
for items in data['items']:
    links.append('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + items['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])

'''
for items in links:
    print items
'''
print "num items: " + str(len(links))

print "Random link: "

print links[random.randint(0, len(links) - 1)]
```

This is my implementation to generate random youtube links from a playlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the data use html requests
And you will get the playlist as JSON data
For example

```
import requests,json
key = 'YOUR API KEY'
playlistid = 'PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE'
data = json.loads(requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={}&key={}'.format(playlistid,key)).text)
print(data)
```

the resoult will be

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Wu2llbfqCdxIVjGbVPm2DslKPCA/_HwI6Wa-Ku-4k5VAHT1GRPH2his\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 13,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"Wu2llbfqCdxIVjGbVPm2DslKPCA/4MX9K88_OdrfvVVaQ2ys5BdQtI8\"",
   "id": "UExCQ0YyREFDNkZGQjU3NERFLkE2OTA3QzIwNEI3RjYxMDE=",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2013-10-18T14:55:24.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCvceBgMIpKb4zK1ss-Sh90w",
    "title": "Andrew Willis, Skatepark Engineer",
    "description": "Andrew Willis built a skatepark in East London using reclaimed materials left over from the Olympic Games, creating a lasting legacy for the local community of Hackney Wick.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GvgqDSnpRQM/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GvgqDSnpRQM/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GvgqDSnpRQM/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GvgqDSnpRQM/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Google Search Stories",
    "playlistId": "PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "GvgqDSnpRQM"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"Wu2llbfqCdxIVjGbVPm2DslKPCA/PBY3vMCXQ8JLWA2_X9BSSpasHUo\"",
   "id": "UExCQ0YyREFDNkZGQjU3NERFLjU5NzE2QkNERURDRTE5NDc=",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2011-09-23T04:52:44.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCvceBgMIpKb4zK1ss-Sh90w",
    "title": "Private video",
    "description": "This video is private.",
    "channelTitle": "Google Search Stories",
    "playlistId": "PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE",
    "position": 1,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "fIc_VEQ7Vo0"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"Wu2llbfqCdxIVjGbVPm2DslKPCA/y4jkKn0lC3ggyxUi8Xr1NXcGPjA\"",
   "id": "UExCQ0YyREFDNkZGQjU3NERFLkZGQjNGMEFDQ0U0MzBCMzc=",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2011-11-22T15:29:40.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCvceBgMIpKb4zK1ss-Sh90w",
    "title": "Mark Lesek: A New/Old Prosthetic",
    "description": "Follow Mark on Google+: https://plus.google.com/u/0/114778778979884307299/about\r\n\r\nMark lost his arm several years ago. Now his search for a better prosthetic could improve the lives of amputees everywhere.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/V4DDt30Aat4/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/V4DDt30Aat4/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/V4DDt30Aat4/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/V4DDt30Aat4/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Google Search Stories",
    "playlistId": "PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE",
    "position": 2,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "V4DDt30Aat4"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"Wu2llbfqCdxIVjGbVPm2DslKPCA/9uUzwGG9HqDu7g3ZMZw3TYWlBOs\"",
   "id": "UExCQ0YyREFDNkZGQjU3NERFLkFBRDU2ODRCNTgwMzA2RTQ=",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2011-10-20T01:02:11.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCvceBgMIpKb4zK1ss-Sh90w",
    "title": "Private video",
    "description": "This video is private.",
    "channelTitle": "Google Search Stories",
    "playlistId": "PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE",
    "position": 3,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "07718Vcwcyc"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"Wu2llbfqCdxIVjGbVPm2DslKPCA/x8utLR6SK07clGh9DQzv80Mczyw\"",
   "id": "UExCQ0YyREFDNkZGQjU3NERFLkMyQjUzQkM1OTFFRTNFMEQ=",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2011-11-22T15:29:40.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCvceBgMIpKb4zK1ss-Sh90w",
    "title": "Mark Kempton: Neighbors In Need",
    "description": "Follow Mark on Google+: https://profiles.google.com/u/0/105705606437451864842\r\n\r\nWhen floodwaters hit northeast Australia, Mark's innovative search became the difference between life and death for many of his neighbors.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XDgC4FMftpg/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XDgC4FMftpg/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XDgC4FMftpg/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XDgC4FMftpg/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Google Search Stories",
    "playlistId": "PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE",
    "position": 4,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "XDgC4FMftpg"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is more straightforward. Easy to access the pages via page tokens too