# YouTube API nextPageToken returning unusable results

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on loading the next page of a returned list, using the Python googleapiclient.  My first query returns a nextPageToken:

```
videos = api_service.search().list(
            part='snippet',
            maxResults=20,
            forMine=True,
            type='video').execute()
```

The page token returned looks something like this:

```
'nextPageToken': 'Cib39GFvs_____81QzNjeU5TRXRMTQD_Af_-NUMzY3lOU0V0TE0AARAUIdZeR03mYiWvOQAAAABMkJ4LSAFQAloLCc8daUP6sg3iEAJgjv3Z_gQ='
```

In all the documentation I've found, page tokens are almost always a 6 character string like this: `CA8QAA`.

- [Example 1 – Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination)
- [Example 2 – Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14568960/9873243)

When I query again sending the pageToken returned to me, I get the same initial video results returned:

```
videos = api_service.search().list(
            part='snippet',
            maxResults=20,
            pageToken=request.GET.get('next_page_token'),
            forMine=True,
            type='video').execute()
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Notice `=` sign at the end of the token `...Jgjv3Z_gQ=`.

The token was making it over to the client correctly.  However, as soon as I tried to do a GET, the `=` was converting to unicode `%3D`

My solution was to not pick up the token from the client.  Instead, I've loaded it into the server session as a string and am passing it directly through the `googleapiclient` library.

My code now reads:

```
if request.GET.get('next_page_token'):
        page_token = request.session['next_page_token']
else:
    page_token = ''

videos = api_service.search().list(
    part='snippet',
    maxResults=50,
    pageToken=page_token,
    forMine=True,
    type='video').execute()

try:
    request.session['next_page_token'] = videos['nextPageToken']

except KeyError:
    pass
```